# solve limit: $\frac43\lim_{k\to ∞} \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{(2n+1)}{(n^2+n)^2}$

Tags: limits

how to solve

> $$\frac43\lim_{k\to ∞} \sum_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{(2n+1)}{(n^2+n)^2}\right)$$

and I try to get..

> $$=\frac43\lim_{k\to ∞} \sum_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{(2n)}{(n^2+n)^2}+(\frac{(1)}{(n^2+n)^2}\right)$$

and how I can do next?

Comment: Note that your sum is telescopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2n+1}{(n^2+n)^2}=\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{n^2(n+1)^2}=\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\dfrac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2} = \dfrac1{n^2} - \dfrac1{(n+1)^2}$$ and then you are done.